# How could this "complex method" for codeclimate be refactored?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm trying to figure out how to refactor some code based on what codeclimate is telling me.  So far it seems that any method that is longer than 5 lines or has an `if` statement is "complex". In this instance, I'm trying to create an event for a calendar based off of a meeting record.

Here is the `Event` model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :eventcolor_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :meeting
  belongs_to :eventcolor

  def self.create_from_meeting(meeting, eventcolor)
    meeting.meeting_date_end ||= meeting.meeting_date_start
    Event.find_or_initialize_by(meeting_id: meeting.id) do |e|
      e.title = meeting.title
      e.datetime_start = Time.zone.local_to_utc(meeting.meeting_date_start)
      e.datetime_end = Time.zone.local_to_utc(meeting.meeting_date_end)
      e.location = meeting.location
      e.address1 = meeting.address1
      e.address2 = meeting.address2
      e.city = meeting.city
      e.state = meeting.state
      e.zip = meeting.zip
      e.description = (!meeting.description.blank?) ? meeting.description : ''
      e.eventcolor_id = eventcolor
      e.save
      e.committees << meeting.committee if !meeting.committee.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

which is called from my `meetings_controller` with this line:

```
Event.create_from_meeting(meeting, params[:eventcolors_select])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things caught my eye:

- You don't check whether `e.save` actually worked. If it fails, you'll have problems down the line.
- `meeting.meeting_date_end ||= meeting.meeting_date_start`
  Don't set an attribute on a record you don't "own"! In this case, a meeting object is being passed to the method to be copied - not altered. Use a local variable instead. It could be a nasty surprise to other parts of the code, to find that the meeting's been altered. Treat the meeting as strictly read-only.
- Why are some of your `meeting`'s date/time-attributes prefixed with the class name? It's redundant; they're attributes on a `Meeting` instance, so there's no reason to name them `meeting_*`. You also prefix `event.datetime_start` with the type, which isn't Ruby-like or Rails-like either. In both cases, something like `starts_at` and `ends_at` would be more than enough. It'd follow the convention set by `updated_at` and `created_at` and be immediately recognizable.
- Speaking of, why are your meeting's date/time attributes defined in the local timezone? I'd advice you to store *everything* as UTC, so you don't have to worry about conversion (as you do in your current code). Because timezone conversion always ends up being painful.
- `e.description = (!meeting.description.blank?) ? meeting.description : ''`
  The parentheses aren't necessary, but moreover there's the `present?` method, which does what you want here: The opposite of `blank?`.
  However, you could also just do `e.description = meeting.description || ''` since `blank?` triggers on `nil`s and empty strings, but the latter is the default anyway, so you really only want to default in case of `nil`.
- Similarly, this `if !meeting.committee.nil?` can be written a few other ways:

  ```
  unless meeting.commitee.nil?
  if meeting.commitee.present?
  if meeting.commitee
  ```

  The last one is the simplest and clearest, but all of them are, to my eyes, better than saying "if the committee is *not not there*"
- My biggest concern is that *this is a lot of data duplication* - seemingly for no reason. Since `Event` already belongs to a `Meeting`, why duplicate anything? Everything should be available since you have `event.meeting`. Duplicating everything doesn't really make sense as long as you have the `Meeting` record. All you gain is the task of keeping two separate sets of data in sync whenever one changes. To me, this approach doesn't really make sense.

So I'd stick with:

```
event = meeting.events.create(eventcolor_id: params[:eventcolors_select])
```

and maybe add some accessor methods (decorators) to `Event` to give you the correct `datetime_start` and `datetime_end`. No need for the method at all.

Semantically, I'd prefer to have it flipped the other way, though: Make a meeting `belong_to` an event. A calendar event is a pretty generic entity: It can be anything with a time and (optionally) a place. A *meeting*, meanwhile, is a more specific thing. So to my mind, it'd make more sense to have a meeting attached to a calendar event, rather than the other way around.

Or you can do Single Table Inheritance with `Event` as the parent class. Or have an even more generic model - or models - the wrap the time and/or place, and have both `Event` and `Meeting` refer to that.

Basically, there are many ways to handle this *without* duplicating data.

---

Meanwhile, just looking at the code as-is, you can get rid of *some* lines:

```
# Note: May raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
def self.create_from_meeting(meeting, eventcolor)
  Event.find_or_initialize_by(meeting_id: meeting.id) do |e|
    # copy all the identically-named attributes
    %w(title location address1 address2 city state zip description).each do |attribute|
      e.send("#{attribute}=", meeting.send(attribute))
    end
    e.datetime_start = Time.zone.local_to_utc(meeting.meeting_date_start)
    e.datetime_end = Time.zone.local_to_utc(meeting.meeting_date_end || meeting.meeting_date_start)
    e.eventcolor_id = eventcolor
    e.save! # raises an exception if it fails
    e.committees << meeting.committee if meeting.committee
  end
end
```

But it's still not very pretty, just shorter. Again, the main issue is the duplication.

Comment: Great notes.  I agree with all of them, but for the love of all that's holy please follow the UTC advice especially!